# Validating Multiple Textfields isEmpty with Json data isNull in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, if-statement, uitextfield

I have 15 uitextfields in that I want to validate like, if one particular uitextfield is empty and for that textfield json data is not empty, then assign a value from json api to that particular uitextfield.

```
if textFieldO.text == "" && json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textOn != nil {
     textFieldO.text = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textOn
}
if textFieldu.text == "" && json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textip != nil {
     textFieldu.text = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textip
}
if textFieldw.text == "" && json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textwi != nil {
     textFieldw.text = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textwi
}
if textFieldq.text == "" && json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textqt != nil {
   textFieldq.text = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textqt
}
if textFieldy.text == "" && json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textyoo != nil {
   textFieldy.text = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textyoo
}
.
.
.
.
if textField15.text == "" && json.childArr[0].childPara[0].text159 != nil {
   textField15.text = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].text159
}
```

--

```
{
  "childArr":[
    "childPara":[
       "text159":"value",
       "textOn":"value",
       "textwi":"value",
       "anotherKey":"value",
       "textqt":"value",
       "textip":"value",
       "text159":"value",
       "textyoo":"value",
     ],
     "childTPara": [],
  ],
  "childIArr":[],
}
```

This has so many `if statement` and we shouldn't have more than 5 `if statement` in code. Even when using `if let` it comes 15 `if let statement` to check the functionality. Kindly help to make it validate and work faster.

Comment: can you paste code using which you are storing values against these 
json.childArr[0].childPara[0].text159

Comment: IBOutlet collections is your answer once you paste code i will be able to send you code accordingly.

Comment: yes sure, i have included @MuhammadAfzal

Comment: i will be sending you better solution in a while.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of solutions. One of them

```
    let childPara = json.childArr[0].childPara[0]

    let array = [
        (textFieldO, childPara.textOn),
        (textFieldu, childPara.textip),
        (textFieldw, childPara.textwi),
        (textFieldq, childPara.textqt)
    ]

    array.forEach { element in
        if element.0.text == "" && element.1 != nil {
            element.0.text = element.1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

// Create outlet collections of your textfield and from identity inspector set accessibility identifier to key of textfield you wanted to feed text from json. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
@IBOutlet var allFields: [UITextField]!

for textField in allFields {
            // You need to store "text159":"value", as key and value in a object.
            let obj = json.childArr[0].childPara[0].filter({$0.key == textField.accessibilityIdentifier})
            textField.text = obj.first?.value
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different key-values in to validate, I think you have to do it (hope to see better ideas). you could also use textfield arrays still the key-value from the json would make the validation a bit tricky. What I think is you could write a method and call it. Something like below

```
private func set(textField: UITextField, value: String?) {
    guard !textField.hasText else {
       return
    }

    textField.text = value ?? "defaultValue"
}
```

you could use this method like

```
set(textField: textFieldO, value: json.childArr[0].childPara[0].textOn)
```

I would recommend to use struct model to keep the json data so that you can easily use it

Comment: `textField.text == nil` is pointless. It will **NEVER** return `true`. `UITextField` default value is an empty string `""`. Even if you assign `nil` to it and check right after it it will return `false`.

Comment: That's true, I made the change.

Comment: `UIKeyInput` has a property called `hasText`  exactly for this purpose since iOS10. `guard !textField.hasText else {` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext?language=swift